# How to say "being" as in "Being jewish"

Tags: grammar

I've always had some difficulty trying to translate the english "being" as in "being Christian" or "being American". I'd like to say 
"in the U.S. being Jewish isn't difficult."

Should I say 我在美国成为犹太人并不难  ?

I feel like 成为 in this instance implies becoming - which is not quite what I am trying to imply.

Comment: How about "當"? Like "我在美国當一個犹太人并不难"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is **作为**

> in the capacity, character, or role of; as
>
> **作为你的朋友，我得劝劝你**
>
> As your friend, I have to give you some advice
>
> **你作为领导，就要以身作则**
>
> As a leader, you should set a good example for others -*A Chinese English Dictionary*

This is basically the equivalent of *as* in English - which I think is what you're looking for with 'being'.

being Jewish 作为一个犹太人

being American 作为一个老美

being Christian 作为一个基督徒

Answer (score 7):

Another option for you is `当`.

`我在美国当犹太人并不难。`

`我在美国当作犹太人并不难。`

`我在美国作为犹太人并不难。`

These all are quite equivalent in saying "Being Jewish in the USA is not hard."

`当` implies a sense of being, filling a role, or acting as something. I do like the aforementioned `作为` as well, and it can be used in just about the same way. Personally, I prefer `当` because it sounds more active, and `作为` feels passive. It's really up to you however.

Comment: 当 makes it sound like being Jewish is a temporary condition.

Comment: @200_success I suppose it depends what you are trying to convey. 当 can denote a hypothetical condition, so it could be used if you weren't Jewish but were talking about what it would be like being Jewish.

Answer (score 5):

"being Jewish" can be translated as "身為一個猶太人"

But for "In the U.S., being Jewish isn't difficult.", I would say "猶太人在美國生活大都不錯".